# How to show infowindow when clicking the polyine

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-polyline

I'm creating a project for my internship, and I have some planes moving on a polyline in google maps [as shown here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/if6b9.png)

First I tried to research for a click event when clicking the path symbol but I couldn't find anything because I need a marker. So then I tough when clicking on the polyline, but I can't find anything that works properly and I have almost no experience and that's why I am asking for help.

I have 4 of these and I need an event for each one because the infowindows will be different, I guess...

```
var GRU = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [{lat: 38.771183, lng: -9.131135}, {lat: -23.6276104, lng: -46.6568016}], //Lis - GRU
    strokeOpacity: 0.1,
    icons: [{
            icon: planeSymbol,
            offset: '0'
        }],
    map: map
});
```

I will appreciate a lot any help you can give to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add event listener with `addListener`:

```
  var handlePolyClick = function(eventArgs, polyLine) {
    // here you can handle the poly
    alert('clicked on ' + polyLine.sometitle);
  };

  google.maps.event.addListener(GRU, 'click', function(e) {
     handlePolyClick(e, this);
  });
```

Working [fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/ishukshin/9y2pt8w9/).

P.S. you can find click's coordinates in `e.latLng` property of an event. Example with infowindow [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ishukshin/4qzmr9ba/9/).

Comment: Thx a lot for your answer!! Yeah it worked perfectly as you showed, but it's not that what I want, because it has that "Prevent this page of creating additional dialog" option, and I need something smooth and inside the map, like a google maps infowindow. 1 more time I'm very appreciated for your help!

Comment: Done! glad for your help

Comment: Thanks. P.S. what an offensive profile. Russian bad words inspires you?)

Comment: it was just a joke! i'm sorry i will change it just now!